# How to import local typescript module?

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, typescript-typings

I am building a TypeScript module and I want to eventually publish to NPM but I first want to import it into another local host project to test. Both projects are in TypeScript.

The module successfully compiles with `tsc` and outputs what appears to be correct files into the `dist` directory. The module includes a [storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) that imports and compiles the module successfully through relative local paths.

In the host project I have tried both `npm link` and local `npm install ../localmodule` to import the module.

The module tsconfig is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./src/types"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

The module `package.json` has

```
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
```

When I then try to compile the host project with the local module imported I get a bunch of errors that I am not seeing in the modules `storybook` or during development.

1. A critical path error that indicates the host project is not seeing one of modules exports is missing or not found.

```
<e> ERROR in ../react-regl/dist/index.js 9:18-51
<e> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/ReglFrame' in '/Users/kevzettler/code/react-regl/dist'
<e>  @ ./src/Ground.ts 6:0-30 11:11-21 12:15-27 20:26-30 31:13-17
<e>  @ ./src/RenderStore.ts 24:0-48 271:12-24 292:12-18 488:28-40 497:28-34
<e>  @ ./src/ClientStore.ts 18:0-40 74:32-43
<e>  @ ./src/browser.worker.ts 1:0-40 10:20-31
<e>  @ ./src/index.ts 83:21-77
```

This export is confirmed in the modules `dist` directory:

```
kevs-mbp:react-regl kevzettler$ ls dist/components/
ReglFrame.d.ts      ReglFrame.d.ts.map  ReglFrame.jsx
```

1. And some type errors that indicate the host project is missing or infering the types differently than the `storybook`

```
<e> ERROR in /Users/kevzettler/code/hypeworks/src/Ground.ts
<e> ./src/Ground.ts
<e> [tsl] ERROR in /Users/kevzettler/code/hypeworks/src/Ground.ts(17,17)
<e>       TS2339: Property 'clear' does not exist on type 'ReactRegl'.
<e>  @ ./src/RenderStore.ts 24:0-48 271:12-24 292:12-18 488:28-40 497:28-34
<e>  @ ./src/ClientStore.ts 18:0-40 74:32-43
<e>  @ ./src/browser.worker.ts 1:0-40 10:20-31
<e>  @ ./src/index.ts 83:21-77
<e>
<e> ERROR in /Users/kevzettler/code/hypeworks/src/Ground.ts
<e> ./src/Ground.ts
<e> [tsl] ERROR in /Users/kevzettler/code/hypeworks/src/Ground.ts(19,21)
<e>       TS2339: Property 'texture' does not exist on type 'ReactRegl'.
<e>  @ ./src/RenderStore.ts 24:0-48 271:12-24 292:12-18 488:28-40 497:28-34
<e>  @ ./src/ClientStore.ts 18:0-40 74:32-43
<e>  @ ./src/browser.worker.ts 1:0-40 10:20-31
<e>  @ ./src/index.ts 83:21-77
```

I can confirm these `clear` and `texture` methods are defined on the `.d.ts` files from the module.

The host projects tsconfig looks like

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2019",
      "dom"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "./src/server.worker.ts",
      "./src/server.ts",
      "./src/network/ServerNetwork.ts",
      "./src/Worker/implementation.worker_threads.ts"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using webpack during compilation in your host project. If so you will need to specify `.jsx` in the [resolve.extensions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensions) property of your webpack config file so that your host project can recognize modules with those extensions. Here's an example `webpack.config.js` using `resolve.extensions` with `.js`, `.jsx`, and `.json`.

```
module.exports = {
  // your other config here...
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks @JoshA I was indeed missing `.jsx` resolve in the host project. But furthermore I added `"jsx": "react",` to the module `tsconfig` so that it would export default `es5`. The host project is unfortunately still missing types on the module that should be included. Any thoughts? I added more detail to the question

Comment: I can't really say what's causing the `Property .. does not exist on type ...` errors unless I see more of the source code unfortunately. I assume the `ReactRegl` being mentioned in the error message is some sort of wrapper for the `regl` library? How is it being referenced inside `Ground.ts`?

Comment: Good call on adding `"jsx": "react"` btw!

Comment: ok I figured out the typing issue. I had a conflicting type definition for `deferred-regl` in both the host project and the module project. The copy in the host project did not have the correct implementation

Answer (score 0):

make a file with extension {{name}}.d.ts

global.d.ts

```
declare module "your-module-name";
```

Comment: The module has its own `.d.ts` file that it exports and I do not want to commit a `{{name}}.d.ts` file to the host project because it will eventually `npm install` the module

Comment: you can add include in your tsconfig
`"include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
, "src/public-path.ts", "src/public-path.ts", "src/main.ts"  ]`